# 403:You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, web, server

I'm facing the following message when I visit my website:

> You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

I am able to visit my other website in same URL, as in `http://xiukun.wang/scrapy/`, but `http://xiukun.wang/datavis/` doesn't work.

I have tried many methods to solve it, like editing my `httpd.conf` file, however it doesn't work. How do I solve it?

```
<Directory "/alidata/www">
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/alidata/www"
<Directory "/alidata/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: apache+php+wordpress+aliyun server，Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed anything in your .htaccess file? Also did you change anything in config file such as DB name user and pass?

Also update the permissions to 755 of your public_html.

**EDIT**

Since you specified its apache, try these solutions:

- Can you open your APACHE config file and find out the index name?
- Check your Directive DirectoryIndex and make sure your index is listed, or else upload:

  ```
     DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml
  ```

  Check for correct dir permissions:

  ```
  <Directory "/home/domain/www">
          Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
          AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ```
- Modify file system permissions of Home directory that APACHE is
  installed:

  ```
  #chmod a+x /apache-home-dir-of installation
  ```
- Make sure the CGI script requested have executable permissions set on
  files. Use chmod command to set permission:

  ```
  $ chmod +x file.cgi
  ```
- Check APACHE logs for errors:

  ```
  # tail -f /path/to/apache/error.logs
  ```

Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!!